# How to populate a drop-down box from a MySQL table in Angular 4

Tags: php, mysql, angular

In PHP and HTML I just simply used to fetch data in array and show it in the select box as shown below:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database-name');

$sql = "SELECT nameid FROM PC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='PcID'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['nameid'] . "'>" . $row['nameid'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

I mean I can connects to a MySQL database, issue query, and outputs `<option>` tags for a `<select>` box from each row in the table

But how do I achieve same in Angular 4?

The best way is to fetch data in a JSON and then show it on the frontend by creating an API? Or there is some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to return the data as JSON. Using rxjs subscribe you can fetch the data like this

```
 users:any[]= [];
fetchData(){
  this.http.get("users/all-users")
      .subscribe((res)=>{
        this.users = res.data
       })

  }
```

So in the html it would be something like

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" value="user.id">
  {{ user.name }}
</option>

 </select>
```

So in your php return data like this

```
function getUsers(){

  mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
   mysql_select_db('database-name');

   $sql = "SELECT nameid FROM PC";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

  return ["data"=>$result];
 }
```

Advice though instead of using normal php use a framework like laravel/yii2 which makes returning data easy.

NB: Angular4  is  a frontend framework so you cannot using echo like you would use it in a php framework.

Comment: ok so basically i need to use json..alright great ,  i am used to work in straight php, never used laravel, i am used to do something like this - https://pastebin.com/sM2Ki6bQ  , PLEASE ADVISE SHALL I CONTINUE LIKE THIS or CHANGE MY WAY OF WORKING

Comment: Thats also fine now when accessing the data youll access .Records. Its also okay to use normal php mysql but later you can check on a framework which provides a better coding standard and also much of the data retrieval logic is already implemented out of the box so you dont need to write alot of code.